# JasperReports: Time series chart

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm new to `JasperReports` and it own related technologies.

And I look for a guide for the time series chart, becuase I read the book but in the chart chapter is shown only pie chart and it is too simple

Kindly regards!

Joksy

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-reporting-%E2%80%93-part-4) seems pretty straight forward.

It should point you in the right direction.

Please note jasper reports uses the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html) library so you might need to download it.

Comment: Great thanks a lot!!! Anyway I move completely to  JfreeChart for build chart and importing in a pdf with itext, because some requirement are not so easy to do in JR. And due the lack of docs and the answer in the forum came after many days i prefer do it all with this tools.

Comment: @Alex Glad I could help, please except the answer or up vote if I helped.